# How to get camera Aspect ratio in VTK?

Tags: python, vtk

I'm working on a web application that allows you to send from the server to the client a picture made ​​with VTK. And to speed up the work, I decided to add to the client webGL. And now i have a question about data synchronization.

On client i use three.js to works with canvas and webGl, and use PerspectiveCamera, and so i need to get camera Aspect ratio, to initialize it.
And so how to get camera Aspect ratio in VTK?

Comment: probably you didn't refer http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. Probably you didn't mention what you tried ?

Comment: i think it's useless information, but if it's need, i'll edit)